# Display encoded HTML in textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im having trouble with mvc decoding my encoded HTML string when I try to display it in textarea, I tried this:

```
    <textarea rows="3" cols="20" style="width: 80%; height:150px; margin:10px 0px;">
      &lt;iframe allowtransparency='true'...
    </textarea>
```

and this:

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="20" style="width: 80%; height:150px; margin:10px 0px;">
    @(Html.Raw("&lt;iframe allowtransparency='true'..."))
</textarea>
```

But it still displays like `<iframe allowtransparency='true'` instead of `&lt;iframe allowtransparency='true'...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping your ampersands. 
It'll look like

```
<textarea>
    &amp;lt;iframe ...
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really easy I can't belive I didn't figure it out before asking.

Comment: Don't forget to set this as the answer!